# can't run BigInteger in android

Tags: android, biginteger

when i run this program, there is an error. but if i delete BigInteger there is no error. how to declare BigInteger in android?

```
//get key
            String a = editKey.getText().toSTring(); 
            //mengubah ke biner
            byte[] bytes = a.getBytes();
            String bin2="";
            bytes = a.getBytes();
            for (byte b : bytes){
                bin2=bin2+"0"+Integer.toBinaryString(b); //ditambah 0 biar jadi ascci 8 bit
            }
            String[] kunci=bin2.split("");
            String kunci1 = "";
            String kunci2 = "";
            for (int i=0;i<32;i++){
                kunci1 = kunci1 + kunci[i];
                kunci2 = kunci2 + kunci[i+32];
            } 
            BigInteger Kunci1 = new BigInteger(kunci1,2);
            BigInteger Kunci2 = new BigInteger(kunci2,2);
            int key1 = Kunci1.intValue();
            int key2 = Kunci2.intValue();
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Apart from any error, what are you trying to do here? Have a look at this constructor `BigInteger(byte[] value)`.